# How to duplicate a Geth server?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

I have a Geth server which is fully synced, but the second server I have lunched cannot being synced after 2 weeks! I don't know why is this happening, but I decided to test another way.
I setup a new server and now, I would like to know how can I **duplicate Geth server** to have a new one?
For this purpose, I tried a way. I copied all `geth` and `keystore` directories from server 1 to server 2 via SCP in about 1 hour. Everything got finished and I ran the `geth` command, but I received the error below:

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: gap (#9924668) in the chain between ancients and leveldb
```

I would be pleased if you can help me to know the appropriate way of having a duplicated server, or solving the issue mentioned above.

Comment: I don't know anything about duplicating Geth but just a note: if the other server can't get synchronized after 2 weeks it's quite possible it wouldn't stay synchronized even if you managed to duplicate all the data successfully so it would be a useless effort

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, I had not such problem on server 1 and it got synced in 2 days, but after that, 2 times on 2 new servers I faced to this problem. I thought it might be a hardware issue for the the second server, so I removed server completely and setup a third one. But the problem did not solve.

Comment: Are all of them using exactly the same hardware?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, yes all of them were the same, and in one datacenter